# Sum multiple columns with lag function SQL

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, sum, lag

I'm trying to sum 2 fields using SQL. My first field is in the current row (leadTime days), while second field is located on previous row (LeadTime Cumulative).

[image: Expected outcome]

What I've done so far to calculate the filed LeadTime Cumulative

```
CASE
WHEN [ClientNo] <> LAG([ClientNo], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [ClientNo], [Startdate])
THEN [LeadTime days]

WHEN [ClientNo] = LAG([ClientNo], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [ClientNo], [Startdate])
AND DATEDIFF(DD, [Enddate Previous], [Startdate]) > 10
THEN [LeadTime days]

WHEN [ClientNor] = LAG([ClientNo], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [ClientNo], [Startdate])
AND DATEDIFF(DD, [Enddate Previous], [Startdate]) < 10
THEN [LeadTime days] + LAG([LeadTime Cumulative], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [ClientNo], 
[Startdate])

ELSE [LeadTime days]
END
```

The thing it goes wrong, it does't ad up the field leadtime days + lag(leadtime cumulative, 1). It gives me null values:

[image: Current output]

Extra:
If datediff start date en enddate previous record within same client > 10, you have to start counting over
Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(lead_time_days) over (partition by clientno
                                 order by startdate
                                ) as cumulative_lead_time_days
from t
```